# if(isset($_POST()) always false

Tags: php, mysql

the `$_POST` array does not get updated for some reason, not sure why.

here is my code, written in a file called database.php:

```
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'comments_schema';
$host = 'localhost:3306';

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $password, $db);
$field1_name = "";

if(isset($_POST['field1_name'])) {
    $field1_name = $_POST['field1_name'];
}
else {
    echo "something is wrong here";
}
$field_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $field1_name);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO parent_comment(commentid, comment) VALUES   
('.commentid.', '.$field_name.')';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Here is my index.html portion for that part:

```
<form action="database.php" method="post">
    Comments: <input type="text" name="field1_name"/>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="submit query"/>
</form>
```

Any reason why isset always returns false in this case?

Comment: remove $field1_name = "";

Comment: FYI It will always be set if the form is submitted, even if its empty.

Comment: @DhavalPatel: What!?!?

Comment: print_r($_POST); what's the ouput ?

Comment: $field1_name = "";  you set $field1_name  blank.so it needs to be remove.

Comment: also you can use if (!empty($_POST))

Comment: @ShashankShah it is printing out as Array() so it is probably empty

Comment: @DhavalPatel even if i remove it the same error occurs

Comment: try to use if (!empty($_POST)) and check it's working or not

Comment: something is wrong with php configuration! $_POST can't be empty if you submit the form with no values it should print 
array(1) { ["field1_name"]=> string(0) "" } by doing var_dump($_POST);

Comment: i tried doing var_dump($_POST) if the post array was empty, and it printed empty brackets

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I don't know if this is the case but check your max_input_vars value not to be a low number in php.ini

```
php_value max_input_vars 6000 //6K is the value you need


//first if checks if the form was submitted first, so you don't always display the error.
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'comments_schema';
    $host = 'localhost:3306';

    $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $password, $db);
    $field1_name = $_POST['field1_name'] ?? ""; //Use only if you are using PHP 7+ Otherwise leave the code as it was but wrap it inside the outer if. 

    if(empty($field_name)){
        echo "something is wrong here";
    }
    $field_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $field1_name);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO parent_comment(commentid, comment) VALUES ('.commentid.', '.$field_name.')';
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

More info: https://lornajane.net/posts/2015/new-in-php-7-null-coalesce-operator

Comment: this doesn't answer his question but I had no idea about the new `??` operator so on that alone I'm resisting the urge to downvote this :-)

Comment: @billynoah Oh I thought I was answering the question, I misunderstood it. Thanks for the observation, Im gonna try to edit my answer asap. :D